# configuring webpack config file in vue-cli 3

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue-cli

I have just created a base project using command "vue create my-project" Now I am fetching a csv file using fetch API, the issue is as the url of csv file is wrong its always returning me index.html file instead of error. Here is my code:

```
const data = await fetch('/url/path/to/my.csv')
const val = data.text()
// here val always have the same content as of index.html
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: You would want to setup a server to serve that file or import the json file using webpack

Comment: where the webpack config file is located?

Comment: `vue-cli` comes with a json loader. You can just import the json file

Comment: question updated, its actually a csv file not json

Answer (score 3):

Since the title of this question is about "configuring webpack config file in vue-cli 3", let me tell you can customize your webpack configs just changing the **vue.config.js**, that it was automaticaly included in your project root directory with `vue create my-project`, as follows:

// vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // It will be merged into the final Webpack config
    plugins: [
      new MyWebpackPluginExample()
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `vue.config.js, that it was automaticaly included in your project root directory with vue create my-project` I just made a few projects with vue cli 3. None of them have an included `vue.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use fetch to get the json file, you will have to setup a server for the file, at least in a production environment.

But on the client side, you can import the csv file into the webpack module. 
To install [csv loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-loader),

```
npm install csv-loader --save-dev
```

Add the loader to the `webpack.base.config.js` file at `build/webpack.base.config.js` with:

```
{
   test: /\.csv$/,
   loader: 'csv-loader'
}
```

Now load the file into module with:

`import file from './path/file.csv';`

and access the same with the `file` variable.

Comment: @coure2011 Changed to csv